# How to format Number to Currency without decimal point in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var computeST = 2145523
var resultFormat= <-- format the computeST here -->
alert(resultFormat);
```

the display alert should be

> 2,145,523

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
console.log(numberWithCommas(2145523));

function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 36):

To display price/currency without decimal point or fraction digits, use `Intl.NumberFormat` with a few parameters `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` set to `0`.

An example:

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, { 
  style: 'currency', 
  currency: 'USD',
  maximumFractionDigits: 0, 
  minimumFractionDigits: 0, 
}).format(1050.55)
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than the currently accepted one as it doesn’t rely on regexp replacements but rather uses options of the `Intl.NumberFormat` API.

Comment: Worked great for me.  I only had to use supply maximumFractionDigits: 0.  I didn't need to supply minimumFractionDigits: 0.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022.

Comment: @KirkLiemohn, setting up only maximumFractionDigits may lead to `RangeError: invalid digits value: 0` when parsing currency. [See also this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41045289/8811487)