# Range error with toLocaleString() with maximumNumber of digits 0

Tags: javascript

The following works in Chrome:

```
var formatted = (value * 1).toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
```

but IE/Edge and Firefox throw the error:

> RangeError: invalid digits value: 0

The [Mozilla docs for toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

> maximumFractionDigits: The maximum number of fraction digits to use. Possible values are from 0 to 20

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A closer read of the docs for [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) shows that, for USD currency, the default value for `minimumFractionDigits` is 2. Setting both `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` to 0 fixed the issue. From this is seems that in IE and Edge `maximumFractionDigits` must be >= `minimumFractionDigits`, when specifying currency (at least)

```
var formatted = (value * 1).toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 });
```

Comment: This fixes a `maximumFractionDigits is out of range` error in Safari 14 when only `maximumFractionDigits` have been set.

Comment: Wow, this worked for react-native too, thanks o/